# Can't Connect to EC2 Instance from Lambda

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Hi everyone im having trouble trying to figure this out and Ive looked everywhere for answers.

My current setup is I have an EC2 instance that has a SSH Tunnel active on it which connects to my database.

I have no problem connecting from my local to this EC2 Instance using SSH and I can query the DB, but when I try to connect to the EC2 Instance from my lambda I receive error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`

I have allowed all inbound traffic on my EC2 instance, I have allowed all Outbound traffic on my Lambda, I am using the internal IP address of my EC2 instance and both are in the same VPC. Im assuming I shouldnt need to SSH from my lambda to my EC2 instance, can anyone help me figure out wtf is going on.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Are you saying that the Lambda function is trying to connect to a PostgreSQL DB that itself is running on port 5432 on the EC2 instance that's in the same VPC?

Comment: Hey @jarmod In my EC2 instance i have a a ssh tunnel running on port 5432, that tunnel is connected to my Postgres DB. 

Im trying to connect my lambda to the EC2 instance on the same port.

Comment: Why? The PostgreSQL DB is presumably in the same VPC as both the EC2 instance and the Lambda function. Why tunnel via SSH when you can just connect the Lambda function directly to the (private) PostgreSQL DB instance?

Comment: Unfortunately the db is not on AWS, the database is on GCP (AlloyDB)

Comment: When you connect to the DB from your local laptop, you presumably have already set up an SSH tunnel to the EC2 instance, then you can connect your PostgreSQL client to a local port and the traffic is tunneled via EC2 to the database. What is your equivalent of the SSH tunnel in the Lambda to PostgreSQL via EC2 case?

Comment: I dont have a SSH tunnel in the lambda, Im assuming you dont need an SSH tunnel from the lambda to the EC2 instance since its within the same VPC. Doesn't having an SSH tunnel from the lambda to the EC2 instance defeat the whole purpose of the VPC?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Your EC2 instance is not a proxy for the database. Your EC2 instance doesn't listen on port 5432 and proxy inbound connections on that port onwards to the PostgreSQL database. Your EC2 instance listens, presumably, on port 22 and will accept an SSH connection and only an SSH connection. In order for your client (laptop or Lambda function) to connect to the PostgreSQL database, it has to tunnel its PostgreSQL traffic through that SSH tunnel.

Comment: That said, if your GCP database has an allowlist of IP addresses (including your EC2 instance) then you could simply deploy a NAT instance into your VPC, allowlist the public IP of the NAT in GCP, and then route the Lambda function traffic to the database via the NAT. But NAT costs money so investigate the costs before you go down this route.

Comment: Thanks for all the information @jarmod , I had no idea you needed to SSH from the lambda to the EC2 even within the same VPC, creating an SSH tunnel within each lambda invocation doesnt sound like a great idea. Ill look into getting NAT arch that you mentioned. Thanks so much.

Comment: Just to be clear, having to tunnel the PostregSQL traffic through an SSH tunnel to the EC2 instance isn't intrinsically caused by AWS. It's because that's how you've set up secure access to your GCP-hosted database. You could also deploy your client code into the GCP VPC via Cloud Functions or other compute option, of course, without the need to tunnel or NAT from inside an AWS VPC. But I presume you have a good reason to do cross-provider database access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255534/discussion-between-jkode-and-jarmod).

Answer (score 0):

If your `listen_addresses = 'localhost'`, that would allow connection over an ssl tunnel (into the same host as the database is on) while not allowing connections from other hosts on same network which were not using a tunnel.